# Do While is not making loop into selection in vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find and highlight the words and its paragraphs from one array. My words are into a selection range. So I've selected a part of my document, but when I run the macro it highlights just the first occurrence of each word, but into the selection there is more than one. Where is my mistake? Here is my code:

```vb
Sub destacaCabeçalhoManual()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, ArrFnd(), ArrFnd1()
    
    If Not (Selection.Type <> wdSelectionIP) Then
   MsgBox "Nenhum texto foi selecionado" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Por favor selecione o texto antes de prosseguir", _
   vbOKOnly & vbExclamation, "Nada selecionado"
   Exit Sub
End If
    
  'para todos os parágrafos que contêm as palavras
ArrFnd = Array("Órgão:", "Valor\(es\):", "Valor:", _
"Convenente:", "Contratante:", "Recorrente(s):", _
"Câmara Municipal:", "Prefeitura Municipal:", "Órgão Público Concessor:", _
"Representado(s):", "Em Julgamento:", "Exercício:", "Assunto:", "Agravante:", "Agravado:", "AGRAVO")
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  With Selection.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ArrFnd(i)
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found = True
      '.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
      .End = .Sections.Last.Range.End
       .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
  .Start = .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.End
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
    
  End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Word find is kind of "strange" - read this article, it will help you to understand how Word is searching: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/words_fickle_vba_find_property.html. The problem with your code: when the first key word is found and do-loop has finished your selection-object is equal to the end of your "physical" selection - therefore no other words can be found.

Comment: Ike, thank you. I learned a lot that I didn't know from that article. I've been pulling my hair out with this code for days, as the author of the article said. Even so, I couldn't fix my code. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub destacaCabeçalhoManual()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, ArrFnd(), Rng As Range
'para todos os parágrafos que contêm as palavras
ArrFnd = Array("Órgão:", "Valor\(es\):", "Valor:", "Convenente:", "Contratante:", "Recorrente(s):", _
  "Câmara Municipal:", "Prefeitura Municipal:", "Órgão Público Concessor:", "Representado(s):", _
  "Em Julgamento:", "Exercício:", "Assunto:", "Agravante:", "Agravado:", "AGRAVO")
With Selection
  If .Type = wdSelectionIP Then
    MsgBox "Nenhum texto foi selecionado" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Por favor selecione o texto antes de prosseguir", _
      vbOKOnly & vbExclamation, "Nada selecionado"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Set Rng = .Range
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ArrFnd(i)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
      End With
      Do While .Find.Execute
        If Not .InRange(Rng) Then Exit Do
        .Paragraphs.First.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you macropod! I think we're almost there.
When I ran your suggestion, nothing happened in the selected region. So I changed the Text from:
.Text = "[!^13]@" & ArrFnd(i) & "[!^13]@^13"
for:
.Text = ArrFnd(i)
In this way he correctly highlighted all the words in the selected region, but did not highlight the paragraphs.
Where in your code is the part that highlights the paragraphs?

Comment: Now I understand that:
"[!^13]@" represents what is from the beginning of the paragraph to the word and that :
"[!^13]@^13" represents what's after the word to the end of the paragraph, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: It worked in my testing. Try the revised code, which is closer to what you started with.

Comment: I suppressed this part [!^13]@" getting like this ArrFnd(i) & "[!^13]@^13" and then the code worked. I think you just needed to predict that the item coming from the Array might be at the beginning of the paragraph (which was the case.) Therefore, I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!
I'm new here, if I have to finish somewhere, please let me know.

Comment: Yes macropod, after your revision, the code is working very good, again thank you!